# Book recommendation for physical philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-physics

I'm searching for books to read on physical philosophy. A book discussing thought experiments, Mach's principle, the equivalence principle, Boltzmann's demon, etc. One which can be read by layman or someone with physics training and provides insights. I'm sure there must be extensive series on physics by some philosopher?

Comment: On Mach, Einstein, inertia, relativity and gravity try [Jammer, Concepts of Mass in Contemporary Physics and Philosophy](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Concepts_of_Mass_in_Contemporary_Physics/d2aYDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). On thermodynamics (I assume "Boltzmann's demon" is Maxwell's demon) there is a chapter in [Rickles's Philosophy of Physics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Philosophy_of_Physics/O6bIDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), which has much more besides: Laplace's demon, hole argument, Boltzmann brains, EPR, time travel and quantum gravity. Both are accessible.

Comment: The question is far too broad.  https://www.amazon.com/s?k=philosophy+of+physics&crid=3423BLWSJMYD&sprefix=philosophy+of+physics%2Caps%2C443&ref=nb_sb_noss_1

Answer (score 1):

[*Relational Mechanics and Implementation of Mach's Principle with Weber's Gravitational Force*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=4655) by [André K. T. Assis](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/%7Eassis/) is a good combination of physics with the history and philosophy of physics.